# 80x86 assembler printf contents of memory

Tags: windows, assembly, memory, x86, printf

I have to write Windows program in x86 assembler (I'm using flat assembler) which will be printing contents of predefined memory. I wrote:

```
 format PE console 4.0

 include "win32ax.inc"
     start:
                mov eax, [0x00850095]
                cinvoke printf,formatstring, eax
                invoke  Sleep,-1

formatstring    db "%#x"

section '.idata' import data readable

library msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll',\
kernel32,'kernel32.dll'
import  msvcrt,printf,'printf' 
import  kernel32,Sleep,'Sleep'
```

It's not working :C; can you help me with that?

Comment: Which assembler? fasm? Also, define "not working". And why is there no `ExitProcess` at the end of the program?

Comment: Is 0x00850095 an hardcoded address?

Comment: Yes, I'm using fasm. "Not working" - When I run it, I get the message: "program stop working" from Windows. 0x00850095 is address of RAM memory.

Comment: Your `formatstring` doesn't seem to have a NUL terminator.

Comment: Use a debugger to see which instruction faults.  It's probably the load, or it could be after printf returns when execution falls into the format string!  Without showing which instruction faults, this isn't really a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

Your format string is not quite correct.  `"%#x"` should probably be `"%08X"` if you want to print the value of *eax*.  If you want to print the value *located at* the address in *eax* then you need to load the value pointed to by *eax* and pass that to `printf`.

The `%x` format specifier to printf expects an `int` passed in the varargs, so if you want to print one byte at a time, you need to load a byte, zero-extended, into *eax* and then pass *eax* to `printf`.

Comment: `%#x` is a correct format specifier. It tells `printf` to print the value as a hex number with a `0x` prefix.

Comment: @Michael is that a standard `printf` format specifier or a proprietary non-standard extension?  I've never heard of it but if it's standard then that's kind of cool. If it's not standard, then why not use one more byte (`0x%x` instead of `%#x`) and avoid a special case in the printf implementation...

Comment: `%#x` [is standard ISO C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).  It specifies "alternative form", which for hex conversions means a leading `0x` or `0X`.  I suspect the OP's problem is faulting before it reaches this code, from the hard-coded pointer, but without using a debugger for an [mcve] we can't tell.  And BTW, `%x` expects an `unsigned int` which it will print in hex.  And the OP's code is *already* loading from some hardcoded address and passing the result to printf.